# need help in simple multiple login in python

Tags: python

i am trying to make a simple login system for python. i tried several things using break,return. but i cant get pass the login system using the second line in the text file onwards. i can only login through the first line of the text file, i took the code fro an other question but didnt know how to get it to work so i tried to change it so i could understand how it can work. I am extremely new to python. please let me know where i got wrong and how i can change it to get it to work!
format for user.txt is

first name|last name|occupation|id|username|password

John|goh|worker|1|admin|1234

```
import datetime
def check():
   x = 0
   users = open("users.txt").read().split("\n")
   for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split("|")
   while (x < 3):
        username = str(input("Username: \n"))
        password = str(input("Password: \n"))
        f = open('project_AI.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(datetime.now()))
        f.write('\n' + username + '\n')
        f.write(password + '\n')
        f.close()
        for user in users:
            uname = user[4]
            pword = user[5]
            if uname == username and pword == password:
                print("Hello " + user[1] + ".")
                print("You are logged in as: " + user[2] + '.')
                x += 3
            else:
                print('error')
                check()
                x += 1
            return
check()
```

many thanks!!

Comment: can you post a couple of lines of "users.txt" just so that we see its form?

Comment: After the `if` clause you immediately `return` without letting the `for` loop to continue. Read about `for..else` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "return" in the penultimate line is at the wrong indentation, and isn't really needed at all.

As soon as python touches a return, it instantly destroys the function. In your code, after every user it checks, it hits the return. Meaning it will never even reach the second user.

You also want to not use check() within the function, as it will create a clone of itself within itself. The while x < 3 will go through the logic multiple times for you.

```
import datetime
def check():
   x = 0
   users = open("users.txt").read().split("\n")
   for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split("|")
   while (x < 3):
        username = str(input("Username: \n"))
        password = str(input("Password: \n"))
        f = open('project_AI.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(datetime.now()))
        f.write('\n' + username + '\n')
        f.write(password + '\n')
        f.close()
        for user in users:
            uname = user[4]
            pword = user[5]
            if uname == username and pword == password:
                print("Hello " + user[1] + ".")
                print("You are logged in as: " + user[2] + '.')
                x += 3
                return
        print('error')
        x += 1 
check()
```

Comment: i removed the return but after hello, and logged in as:, the error message pops up, loops back to ask me for username and doesnt let me continue to the next part of the code